# Specify QueryString in Html.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

0I want to insert the output of an action into a view.  The problem is that the action requires some info in the querystring.  Is there a way to include the querystring params in Action?

Example:

```
@Html.Action("Get","Contacts")
```

To get the proper result back, I need to pass ?pagenum=1 to the action.

```
@Html.Action("Get?pagenum=1","Contacts")  unfortunately doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@Html.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName", new { pagenum = 1 })
```

Use the overload of `Action()` to define route values.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx)

Is your Action Method really named `Get()`?  If so, and your controller name is `Contacts`, your modified code would need to be:

```
@Html.Action("Get", "Contacts", new { pagenum = 1 })
```