# how to pass a querystring param to url.action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc 5 project. 
Inside a view I want to pass a parameter from the request's query string to an action.
Here's what i did:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("GetData", "TestController", Request.QueryString["param"])"> Click here</a>
```

But this doesn't pass the querystring param.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `@Html.Action("GetData", "TestController", new { param = Request.QueryString["param"] })`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify QueryString in Html.Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440407/specify-querystring-in-html-action)

Comment: You could use `<a href="@Url.Action("GetData", "TestController", new{ parameter = Request.QueryString["parameter"]})">Click here</a>`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use an `ActionLink` helper

```
@Html.ActionLink("GetData", "TestController", new { param = Request.QueryString["param"] })
```